# How to list contents of compressed files in a hierarchy mode?

Tags: command-line, bash, zip, tree

Consider we have a file named `XX.zip`

Use command `zipinfo -1 XX.zip` which shows the below content:

```
XX/
XX/X-Data.txt
XX/YY/
XX/YY/Zero.txt
```

I wanna below output instead, assume we have extracted the zip file `unzip XX.zip` and then use command `tree XX` given output:

```
XX
├── X-Data.txt
└── YY
    └── Zero.txt
```

---

One way to do so is write a bash command to create the hierarchy structure:

```
makefile ()                                                                                                                                                  
{
  while read path; do
      dir=${path%/*}
      filename=${path##*/}

      mkdir -p $dir
      if [ -n $filename ]; then
          touch $path
      fi  
  done
}
```

And then use commands below

```
 zipinfo -1 XX.zip | makefiletree 
 tree XX
 rm -rf XX
```

---

Is there any convenient way to do? any comments will be appreciated.

Comment: Please check [List contents of tarball in tree format](https://superuser.com/q/1086501/370509) also.